# R cannot be resolved to a variable using Android Studio and Google Maps

Tags: android, xml, google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-android-api-2

I am aware that there must be a problem somewhere in the manifest or the XML but I cannot find it. Any help would be appreciated! I've spent a while  trying to figure this but can't get anywhere with it.

Error:Element type "activity" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>". (I cannot see anywhere where tags are a problem)

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.clubnightsdeals"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
  <permission
        android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission   android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- Required to show current location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

     <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:label="@string/clubnightsdeals"
            android:name=".AppActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
       <uses-library
        android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        <activity
            android:label="@string/clubnightsdeals"
            android:name=".App2Activity" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
     android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
     android:value="AIzaSyDetfYqNFORnvtRlybuVfht3RIKxKT6DRY" />
          <activity
            android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme"/>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
 
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity

package com.example.clubnightsdeals;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.R;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;






public class AppActivity extends Activity {

    Button button;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    //  addListenerOnButton();s
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        final Context context = this;

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);   

            }


        });

    };
        public void addListenerOnButtonNews() {

        final Context context = this;

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), App2Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);   

            }
        });

        }

        ;

         protected void onCreate11(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.main2);
            }


         //Google Map
         GoogleMap googleMap;

        protected void onCreate1(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main2);

            try {
                // Loading map
                initilizeMap();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } 

        /**
         * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
         * */ 
        private void initilizeMap() {
            if (googleMap == null) {
                googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                        R.id.map)).getMap();

                // check if map is created successfully or not
                if (googleMap == null) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {

            super.onResume();
            initilizeMap();
        }
```

Main.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Club Deals"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="GPS locations" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Closest Deals"
        android:onClick="open_close_deals" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cheapest Deals"
        android:onClick="open_cheap_deals" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Best Value Deals"
        android:onClick="best_value" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Best Events"
        android:onClick="best_events" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="News" 
        android:onClick="news"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Main2.xml

```
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

The errors I am getting say R cannot be found and keeps suggesting I import the wrong version of R.

edit: I have changed the manifest to

```
<activity
            android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme"
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
 
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

but still get errors

Comment: You didn't post all of your manifest file. Could you fill in the top too in case that is where the error lies?

Comment: Sorry, manifest is fixed!

Comment: Did you try Rod_Algonquin's answer? I think he's correct.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that youre importing

```
import com.google.android.gms.R;
```

**solution:**
 remove that so your R.java will be used not the google one..

Answer (score 1):

right here

```
<activity
    android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme"/>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

on this line you close the activity tag

`android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme"/>`

but below you close it again

`</activity>`

Comment: Thanks for your help! I still get an error having changed it to        <activity  
            android:name="info.androidhive.googlemapsv2.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme"
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
 
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: I'll add what I changed it to in the main section as it's hard to read there.

Comment: do you now know how XML works? you need a start tag and an end tag, you dont have a start tag now because you removed `>` from the activity

Comment: Hey, The error on the manifest is gone now, I just needed to clean it which is what confused me after I fixed that problem. The manifest is no longer throwing up errors. I fixed it since copy pasting above. The R import however, is still not working for me.

Comment: then there is an error in another of your xml files